# Better way to write this 3+3 math problem by using loops?

Tags: c#, loops, math, tags

I'm a beginner in C# and I'd like to know if there a better way to write this 3+3 math problem by using loops, like maybe a do while loop ?

My code is the following :

```
static void Main (string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine ("What is 3+3?");
        int answer = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
        int counter = 1;

        if (answer == 6) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Great! thats Correct! you've got it in the first try");
        } else {
            while (answer != 6) {
                Console.WriteLine (" Wrong, please try again");
                answer = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
                counter++;

                if (answer == 6) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Correct! Well done! you got it in {0} tries", counter);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine ();
}
```

The aim of this program is to ask the user a question, check the answer and output a statement that says how many tries the user took to get the answer right.

If you could provide me suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting less code / a more concise option you could go for either of the following.
Note I've ignored the use of a slightly different error message for the first case and other cases. If this is important then you can of course have an `if (counter == 1)` statement.

This first example uses Do/While which will always execute the loop at least once and then check the exit condition (`answer == 6`) at the end of every loop.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is 3+3?");

        int answer;
        int counter = 0;

        do
        {
            answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            counter++;

            if (answer == 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct! Well done! you got it in {0} tries", counter);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Wrong, please try again");
            }
        }
        while (answer != 6);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This second example uses a while loop that loops forever and the break keyword which breaks out of a loop once a certain condition is met. This prevents the need for extra if statements to get rid of pesky extra messages etc.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is 3+3?");

        int answer;
        int counter = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            counter++;

            if (answer == 6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct! Well done! you got it in {0} tries", counter);
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" Wrong, please try again");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This was very useful i never knew about the true while loop and break keyword so its great to learn new things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very much about this, but at least, in C++, when you fail, I invoked again the main method with Main();, adding the error message.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using do/while will be significantly shorter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 1;
    boolean hasAnswer = false;
    do {        
        Console.WriteLine("What is 3+3?");
        int answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (answer == 6)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Great! thats Correct! You've got it in " + counter + " attempt(s)");
            hasAnswer = true
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Wrong, please try again");
            counter++;
        }
    } while(!hasAnswer);
}
```

I haven't rewritten C# in a while so the syntax might be off, but that is the gist of how to do it.

Comment: If you want to be fancy you can also change the while condition to:
   } while(answer != 6);

but I think using booleans is easier to understand...

Comment: Thanks for the response and it worked! :) could you please explain why you have set has hasanswer to false? and i'm not sure about what while(!hasAnswer) means.

Comment: In this example `hasAnswer` is just a boolean variable that denotes whether the correct answer has been found yet and therefore it starts off as false. `while(!hasAnswer)` means loop again if `hasAnswer == false`. `!` means logical not, so basically `while not hasAnswer == true`